# Import Error: No module named snappy

Tags: python, snappy

I am trying the software SNAP in Python. I have installed SNAP and the module Snappy. But when I try to import snappy through python GUI I am getting this error:

> Import Error: No module named snappy

My python version is 2.7.10. I have checked the bit compatibility of SNAP and Python it's ok.

snap installed in cmd, here's the Python GUI error:

[image]

How can I solve it?

Comment: The path that you append should not have the last component (`'\\snappy'`). A path is the name of the folder where Python will search for your modules, not the name of the module folder .

Comment: Have you given the name of your file snappy? If so, change the name of your file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path that you append should not have the last component ('\snappy'). A path is the name of the folder where Python will search for your modules, not the name of the module folder. This solved it @DYZ

Answer (score 0):

I tried doing both the changes. I removed the last component and got the following error.[error 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hiUWW.png)

I changed the name of the folder containing snap and still got an error[error2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Cxahx.png)